# Table partitioning in sql server - how do you ensure it wins a deadlock over queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, partitioning

The bane of my existence is when the MERGE on a table partition gets deadlocked and eventually loses.

I've tried setting the deadlock_priority to high.

I have code that kills each query hitting the tables beforehand, but sometimes I still get a query in there during those milliseconds.

I'm at a loss.  Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't deadlock_priority work? It should. Can you show some code?

Comment: @Blam Hadn't thought of trying a tablock, that might be a way.

Comment: @usr It's always during the merge, too.  We have a few thousand records in the oldest partition, that's probably why there's any delay.  `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH; ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfdaily()  MERGE RANGE (@Day_In) ; SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL;`

Comment: @mbourgon I'd file a bug report on MS Connect. This doesn't seem right. Maybe the merge is having multiple internal transactions, not all of them inheriting the deadlock priority. Anyway, can you manually lock the entire partition before acting on it?

Answer (score 1):

You must use hints in order to lock the objects that are used by the merge statement -xlock,holdlock. 
My advice is to start the sql Profiler with event Deadlock Graph and try to reproduce the deadlock with a tool (I use this [tool](http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/)) and then to figure out why it is happening. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528303/what-are-common-reasons-for-deadlocks) as initial information.