# Does "Deadlock" occurs due to hardware or it can be cause by software?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

what are the reasons for DeadLock occurrence ? does it cause from Hardware or it can be also cause by software issue?

Comment: Which _hardware_ construct would be able to create a software deadlock? Hitting your PC with a sledge hammer?

Comment: if you didnt ans...then say sorry sir....here always criticism is more and solution is less on StackOverFlow @UweKeim

Comment: if i know then why i put this question here ???? @UweKeim

Comment: You can go through standard books and net before posting any question here.Check http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/OpSystems/Myos/deadlockCondition.htm this may change your perception about deadlock...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Deadlock is strictly only caused by an OS and Software problem. Multiple threads trying to acquire the same resource is the most common cause. You would have been better using Google to find the answer. People are very rude on here.

[What are common reasons for deadlocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528303/what-are-common-reasons-for-deadlocks?)

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075692/java-concurrency/avoid-synchronization-deadlocks.html

Comment: Thanks @CJFreelancing